# How do I move certain body elements to different parts of the screen?

Tags: html, css, image

I have been working on google sites with HTML and CSS, and I wanted to try to get as raw as possible with the code. So I decided to combine some of the code together to have them as one element instead of 2.

After combining, I wanted to figure out how to have each  be separated. I have tried id: inset; but that doesn't seem to work

```html
    <style>
    img{
        border-radius: 75px;
        box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #080808,-5px -5px 10px #181818;
        display: block;
        padding: 5%;
        margin-top: 5%;
        margin-bottom: 5%;
        margin-left: 5%;
        margin-right: 5%;
    }
    body.logo{
        position: center;
        background: #101010;
        id: logo;
    }
    p {
        font-size: 36px;
        font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
        color: white;
        width: 50%;
        margin: 25%;
    }
    body.inset{
        position: left;
        border-radius: 75px;
        background: #101010;
        box-shadow: inset 5px 5px 10px #080808, inset -5px -5px 10px #181818;
        padding: 5%;
        margin: 5%;
        text-align: center;
        id: inset;
    }
</style>
<body id="logo">
<img src=https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=13-tqq4CPvcPQGgv3yoH7GK7xCPfEeB40 style=width:80%>
<body>

<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<style>

</style>
<body id="inset">
    <p>
Website Beta
    </p>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the tour first: https://stackoverflow.com/tour -> then read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - I really have troubles to understand what your question is. Also `body.logo` aswell as `body.inset` proberly a wrong use. There is no reason (just one exeption) to give a body a class. Espacially not 2 different classes when there only can be one body. Also those classes contradict each other. In case you have multiple bodies, then this would be invalid HTML.

Comment: Here is the question simplified: How do I move certain body elements to different parts of the screen?

Comment: your question is still way to broad. You need to be really specific. Also not again, that you cant have more then one body. Everything else will be invalid HTML. Then it depends what elements (block-level, inline, table-cell, flex...) you trying to align and where you want them to align. How do you want them to behave? Grid-layout, independent column layout independent row layout...

Comment: I would like to know how I can set body.logo to the right and body.incline to the left. Yes, I know that those are not the syntax they should be, but I will use that to reference which body I am talking about.

Comment: Please re-read my first comment. You still havent taken the tour and proberly not read the other guideline aswell. Without those details listed in the guidelines it will be ahrd to help you. My best bet would be to recommend flexbox. But I do not know your HTMl structure nor do I know if you have a valid HTML markup (sounds like you have multiple body tags which means it is invalid and should be fixed first).

Comment: Please include your HTML for reference as well. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Don't guess at values for style properties e.g: `position:center` and `position:left` are not valid. Look them up at a reliable source like [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/)

Comment: https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input <- Plkease use the validator to validate your HTML and CSS markup. Currently your code alone contains 13 invalid markup erros. Those need to be fixed before we can actually start to help. In your short codes there are tons of invalid/non-existing commands.

Answer (score 1):

The `body` element can only exist *once*  in an HTML document.

If you create CSS rules for different classes that are applied to `body`, it makes no sense, since all of them will be applied to `body`, that is: if your `body` tag really contains those classes in the HTML code.

It seems you rather want to create and apply classes for *child elements* of `body` - in this case your CSS selectors are wrong: A div with class "xxx" which is a child of `body` won't be selected by a  `body.xxx {...}` selector, but rather by `body .xxx { ... your CSS rules here ... }` - note the space!

But in this case you wouldn't have to use `body` at all in the selector  - `.xxx { ... your CSS rules here ... }` would be sufficient, since *all*  elements are children of `body` (except `html`, of course...).

P.S.: There is no `position: left;` or `position: center` in CSS. Also , adding `id: inset;` to a CSS rule has no effect whatsoever.